# How to load dll dynamically and pass/get value to it?

Tags: c#, dll, dllimport, loadlibrary, getprocaddress

In `DllImport` I can do this:

```
[DllImport(".../Desktop/Calculate.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern int Sub(int a, int b);
```

But I want to decide which dll to load at run time.
So I'm not using `DllImport` but try this:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace TestCall   
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "LoadLibrary")]
        static extern int LoadLibrary([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string lpLibFileName);
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetProcAddress")]
        static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(int hModule, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string lpProcName);
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "FreeLibrary")]
        static extern bool FreeLibrary(int hModule);
        delegate void CallMethod();
        static void Main(string[] arg)  //pass in string array
        {
            string DllName = ".../Desktop/Calculate.dll";  //would be like: string  DllName = ChooseWhatDllToCall();
            string FuncName = "Sub";                       //would be like: string FuncName = ChooseWhatFuncToUse();
            int hModule = LoadLibrary(DllName); // you can build it dynamically 
            if (hModule == 0) return;
            IntPtr intPtr;
            CallMethod action;

            intPtr = GetProcAddress(hModule, FuncName);
            action = (CallMethod)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(intPtr, typeof(CallMethod));
            action.Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

But how can I define `Sub` as `int Sub(int a, int b);` like I'm using `DllImport`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a delegate as follows:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public delegate Int32 Sub(Int32 a, Int32 b);
```

and then, in your code:

```
Sub sub = (Sub)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(intPtr,typeof(Sub));

Int32 a = 5;
Int32 b = 8;
Int32 result = sub(a, b);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need more than one function from the dll, you shall desire automation on this process. It would be so nice to get the delegate in one call, like :

```
IntPtr hModule = LoadLibrary(".../MyLibrairy.dll"); 
var sub = DelegateBuilder<Sub>(hModule, "Sub");
var result = sub((Int32)5, (Int32)8);
```

There it is :

```
public static T DelegateBuilder<T>(IntPtr loadedDLL, string delegateName = null) where T : Delegate
{
    string functionName = delegateName ?? typeof(T).ToString().Split('+').Last();
    IntPtr pAddressOfFunctionToCall = GetProcAddress(loadedDLL, functionName);
    if (pAddressOfFunctionToCall == IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        var errorMessage = string.Format("Not found function <{0}> in dll ", functionName);
        throw new EntryPointNotFoundException(errorMessage);
    }
    T functionDelegate = Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(pAddressOfFunctionToCall, typeof(T)) as T;
    return functionDelegate;
}
```

It is possible to call the result directly and have unreadable code:

```
var result = DelegateBuilder<Sub>(hModule)((Int32)5, (Int32)8);
```

any comment on the code above would be much appreciated 
Special Thx to (Damien.B:)